# How to render another component on submitting a form

Tags: reactjs

In my website first I want to display a page to select a country from a dropdown.
Then I want that on clicking the proceed button another component renders and I also want to pass the country to this component.

This is my country component.

```
const Country = () => {
 const [country, setCountry] = useState("");

 const handleSelect = (e) => {
   setCountry(e.target.value);
 };

 return (
   <div className="container">
     <form action="">
       <label htmlFor="country">Country</label>
       <select name="country" id="country" onClick={handleSelect}>
         <option value="-1">--Country--</option>
         <option value="in">India</option>
         <option value="jp">Japan</option>
         <option value="us">USA</option>
         <option value="br">Brazil</option>
         <option value="ch">China</option>
         <option value="sr">Sri lanka</option>
       </select>
       <button type="submit">Proceed</button>
     </form>
   </div>
 );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
const Country = () => {
  const [country, setCountry] = useState("");
  const [shouldShowComponent, setShouldShowComponent] = useState(false);

  const handleSelect = e => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    setCountry(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleProceed = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setShouldShowComponent(true);
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <form action="">
        <label htmlFor="country">Country</label>
        <select name="country" id="country" onChange={handleSelect}>
          <option value="-1">--Country--</option>
          <option value="in">India</option>
          <option value="jp">Japan</option>
          <option value="us">USA</option>
          <option value="br">Brazil</option>
          <option value="ch">China</option>
          <option value="sr">Sri lanka</option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit" onClick={handleProceed}>
          Proceed
        </button>
      </form>
      {shouldShowComponent && <YourComponent country={country} />}
    </div>
  );
};
```

You add another state variable that determines when to show the component you want to show. This value is updated using the `handleProceed` function.

Then inside the component you retrieve the `country` prop and do something with it.

**Update**

If you want to hide the form after clicking on the button you can do it like this:

```
const Country = () => {
  const [country, setCountry] = useState("");
  const [shouldShowNextPage, setShouldShowNextPage] = useState(false);

  const handleSelect = e => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    setCountry(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleProceed = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setShouldShowNextPage(true);
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      {shouldShowNextPage ? (
        <YourComponent country={country} />
      ) : (
        <form action="">
          <label htmlFor="country">Country</label>
          <select name="country" id="country" onChange={handleSelect}>
            <option value="-1">--Country--</option>
            <option value="in">India</option>
            <option value="jp">Japan</option>
            <option value="us">USA</option>
            <option value="br">Brazil</option>
            <option value="ch">China</option>
            <option value="sr">Sri lanka</option>
          </select>
          <button type="submit" onClick={handleProceed}>
            Proceed
          </button>
        </form>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

But this is not really an approach that scales well, so I recommend you take a look at a library like react router (https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router#readme) if you plan on navigating between a lot of different components.

Comment: Now the only problem is that it is also showing the form on top of the new component.

Comment: Oh that wasn't clear to me you wanted that from your question. So it should be more like navigating to a new page?

Comment: Oh sorry! yes I want that

Comment: So everything works well except that my form and the new component both are shown on same page.

Comment: I know broswer router but dont know how to render a component on a button click using the same. Can you please help me?

Comment: That's out of the scope of this question. But how you would do it is to create a `BrowserRouter` component and put a `Switch` component inside. Inside the `Switch` you can put your `Route` components. Then you can use a `Link` component to navigate to a specific route on click. The `Switch` component makes sure only one of the routes is shown at a time. You can look at this tutorial for more info: https://blog.pshrmn.com/simple-react-router-v4-tutorial/. If you get stuck implementing this I recommend to create a new question instead of adding to this one.

Answer (score 0):

If you use react-router v6 then you can use built in hooks like useNavigate and useLocation. It's very easy just take a look on YouTube.
But if you use react-route v5 I think the best way is to useContext.